# How to get min/max value from 10 numbers with a loop? (C language)

Tags: c, loops

Hi im fairly new in programming and started with C language and now im stuck with loops.
The problem is that I try to write a program that has to get an input value of 10 INT numbers that are greater than 20, and after that the program has to determine which of the numbers is the maximum and which is minimum. at the end it has to calculate the average of all numbers.
So now I managed to get only the average calculation to work correctly, and the main problem is the max/min values.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    //Variables
    int num, i = 1, cnt = 0, sum = 0, max = 0, min = 0;
    float average;

    printf("Enter 10 int numbers greater than 20:\n");

    //Input check
    while (i <= 10)
    {
        printf("\n%d) ", i);
        scanf("%d", &num);
        max = num;
        min = num;
        if (num <= 20)
        {
            printf("Wrong number! enter an integer greater than 20:\n");
            continue;
        }
        i++;
        sum += num;
        cnt++;
        if (num > max) {
            max = num;
        }
        if (num < min) {
            min = num;
        }
    }

    //Average calculation and output
    average = sum / (float)cnt;
    printf("The maximum number is: %d\n", max);
    printf("The minimum number is: %d\n", min);
    printf("The average of all numbers is: %.2f\n", average);
    
}
```

Comment: You need to remove the assignments right after the `scanf()`... just keep the assignments in the `if`s ... oh, initialize `min` to a large number, not `0` ... `int ... min = INT_MAX;` (remember to `#include <limits.h>`)

Comment: Suppose you get `a` on the input stream.  (Try it!).  You *must* check the value returned by `scanf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick check game in c that asks for few numbers and then when you enter 0 it shows you the lowest and highest  number in the array (number collected)

```
int main(){
    int a, max = 0, min;
    char answer;


    while(answer != 'n')
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        printf("Enter Number:");


        if (scanf("%d", &a) == 1)
        {
        if(a == 0)  //check if the input value is 0 then break the loop
            break;
        else
            {
                if(a > max)
                max = a;


                if(a < min)
                min = a;
            }
        }
    }


        printf("lowest: %d, highest: %d", min, max);


        printf("\nWould you like to start over? (j/n): ");
        scanf("%s", &answer);


        max = 0;
        //min=0;


        if(answer == 'n')
            break;
    }

   return 0;
}
```